# BlueSnap virtual terminal - can I just send charge links without a catalog item?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, bluesnap

I am using the BlueSnap VT to sell items to customers - but in a scenario Whenever I want to charge a customer any amount one-off, it's not that convenient for me.

I just want to charge the money and not assign the purchase to anything in particular.
Can I use the VT to just create a link to charge $100, without saying it's for any part of my catalog? If so, what do I need to configure, and is this change permanent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BlueSnap virtual terminal works with products – but I found there's a configuration way around it if you want.

When you login to your account, go to the Settings menu in the top right corner and select the "Virtual Terminal Settings" in the menu. Then in the VT setting page scroll down to find "Product/Contract Selection" drop down menu (it's in the middle). Set it to *"Hide (Use payment page)"*, and click Submit.

Now when you go to the virtual terminal, you can create "payment pages" – basically links where you can ask to charge a certain amount without any cart or products attached. When you finished creating the link, you can go back to the Virtual Terminal settings and set the Product/Contract Selection field back to "Show", to restore your original setup if you prefer.

I hope this helps!